# How to convert list of dict of list of dict with same key as pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a json response like this -

```
{
  "returnedRowCount":2,
  "columns":[
    {"name":"type","type":"TEXT","index":0},
    {"name":"type","type":"TEXT","index":1},
    {"name":"dept","type":"TEXT","index":2}],
  "rows":[
    {"row":[{"v":"type1"},{"v":"name1"},{"v":"dept1"}]},
    {"row":[{"v":"type2"},{"v":"name2"},{"v":"dept2"}]}
    ]
}
```

Need a way to convert to dataframe like below -

```
    type name dept
 0  type1 name1  dept1 
 1  type2 name2  dept1
```

I believe this requires comprehension to convert to dict first but not able to figure it out

Comment: I assume the second column name in your example json shall be `name` instead of `type`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can extract column names and row data using list comprehensions:

```
import pandas as pd

j = {
  "returnedRowCount":2,
  "columns":[
    {"name":"type","type":"TEXT","index":0},
    {"name":"name","type":"TEXT","index":1},
    {"name":"dept","type":"TEXT","index":2}],
  "rows":[
    {"row":[{"v":"type1"},{"v":"name1"},{"v":"dept1"}]},
    {"row":[{"v":"type2"},{"v":"name2"},{"v":"dept2"}]}
    ]
}

data = [[c['v'] for c in r] for r in [row['row'] for row in j['rows']]]
columns = [c['name'] for c in j['columns']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

Result:

```
    type   name   dept
0  type1  name1  dept1
1  type2  name2  dept2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
data = [[vals['v'] for vals in dat['row']] for dat in j['rows']]
pd.DataFrame(data, columns = pd.DataFrame(j['columns'])['name'].tolist())

    type   name   dept
0  type1  name1  dept1
1  type2  name2  dept2
```